# View with height match_parent not visible in recyclerview item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-view

Below is the layout of an item of recyclerview.I want to create a vertical view at left of each item of layout such that it matches the height of the item.I used below code-

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp"  
        android:background="@drawable/foodvitebackground">

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/invitename" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="18dp"
         android:textColor="@color/adsd"
         android:text="fasf"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/name" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_below="@+id/invitename" 
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp" 
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/profileimage" 
         android:gravity="left" 
         android:textColor="@color/foodvite_invitename" 
         android:textSize="20dp" 
         android:text="Fill-a Pita"/>

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/jJoinTime" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_below="@+id/name" 
         android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
         android:textSize="12dp" 
         android:text="Today,8:30PM"
         android:textColor="@color/joinTime"/>

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView  
         android:id="@+id/profileimage"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/hundred_dp"   
         android:layout_height="@dimen/hundred_dp"    
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
         android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/invitescount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="20" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp" 
        android:paddingRight="3dp" 
        android:background="@drawable/ret"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" 
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message"     
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profileimage" 
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/profileimage"/>

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/leftbar" 
        android:layout_width="6dp" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/foodviterespoded"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

With above code i don't see view with id leftbar visible.However if i change  height of that view from match_parent to some numerical value like 160dp then i see the left bar view visible.Why is this happening.And i don't want to set height in numerical value bcoz i want my view to stretch to complete height of item and height of item might be different in different device.

Comment: I want to make sure I understand what you want to do. You want a a `RecyclerItem` that's the full size of it's parent `RecyclerVIew` correct?
With the `android:id="@+id/leftbar"` are you trying to have that item off screen? and only visible when the user scrolls or do you want it to have it's visibility toggled.  
It would help if you could provide a drawing of what you  want with labels.

Comment: @VirtualProdigy No I just want leftbar view to be of same height as the height of an item of a recycler view

Comment: set `android:layout_alignParenTop="true"` & `android:layout_alignParentBottom ="true"`. Then `leftbar` will also be the height of its parent container

Comment: As for making your RecycleItem the height of the parent view, you'll most likely  need to update your adapter. You'll have to grab the implicit height of the 'RecyclerView' and in your 'onCreateViewHolder' of the adapter set your `LayoutParams` for your `RecyclerItem` with the height of the parent

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the recycler view's cell height in the view holder's constructor.

```
itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
height = itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Set the divider's height with the above calculated height in onBindViewHolder()

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams divParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
divider.getLayoutParams();
divParams.height = height;//Add any top or bottom margin(in pixel) specified
divider.setLayoutParams(divParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` set to the View with id "leftbar".

Update:

try this.

```
<View 
        android:id="@+id/leftbar" 
        android:layout_width="6dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/invitename"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/jJoinTime"
        android:background="@drawable/foodviterespoded"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the height as wrap content for the parent relativelayout which is removing the leftbar view. Try setting the parent relative layout height as match parent

Comment: RecyclerView Layout item should not have match_parent height, because it will take the entire screen height. i.e. each row item will be the screen height.